# Replace multiple strings in txt file using Batch and Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, find-replace

I have built a batch file that runs a BTEQ script and returns the data in a txt file. However, I am expanding my code to allow for user input of user_id, password, and a period parameter YYYYMM.
I initially wrote hard coded my personal login information into the BTEQ file and tested with just the snapshot parameter like so.

```
echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P SNAPSHOT="What snapshot should I use [YYYYMM]?"
DEL EXPORT.TXT
POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE \"\?YYYYMM\"", %SNAPSHOT% "} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT";
bteq < test.txt > output.txt 2>&1
POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE " %SNAPSHOT% ,"\"?YYYYMM\"} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT";
@echo off goto end
en @echo exit
```

The code worked as intended. However, when I go to add the userid and password, I simply copy the snapshot code for PowerShell and replaced the variables as needed.

```
echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P USER_ID=Enter User ID:
SET /P USER_PASSWORD=Enter Password:
SET /P SNAPSHOT="What snapshot should I use [YYYYMM]?"
DEL EXPORT.TXT
POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE \"$USER_ID\"", %USER_ID% "} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT";
POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE \"\$USERPASSWORD\"", %USER_PASSWORD% "} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT"; 
POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE \"\?YYYYMM\"", %SNAPSHOT% "} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT";
bteq < test.txt > output.txt 2>&1
::POWERSHELL -COMMAND "(GET-CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE " %SNAPSHOT% ,"\"?YYYYMM\"} | OUT-FILE TEST.TXT";
@echo off goto end
en @echo exit
```

The snapshot code still works but I get errors for the User_ID and User_Password user inputs. As follows:

```
Enter User ID:userTest
Enter Password:TestPass
What snapshot should I use [YYYYMM]?202102

At line:1 char:66
+ ... -CONTENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE "\$USER_ID", userTes ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:67
+ ... TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE "\$USER_ID", userTest } | OUT ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'userTest' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

At line:1 char:71
+ ... ENT TEST.TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE "\$USERPASSWORD", TestPas ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:72
+ ... TXT) | FOREACH-OBJECT {$_ -REPLACE "\$USERPASSWORD", TestPass } | OUT ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'TestPass' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Comment: I do not believe that `$_ -REPLACE \"\?YYYYMM\"", %SNAPSHOT% "`, or `$_ -REPLACE " %SNAPSHOT% ,"\"?YYYYMM\"` are correct syntax, to begin with, _(regardless of your statement that it worked as intended)_. You should be using this syntax, `PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path \".\test.txt\") | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace \"StringBefore\",\"%StringAfter\"} | Set-Content -Path \".\test.txt\""`. I've  changed your `Out-File` to `Set-Content`, and doublequoted `.\test.txt`, just to highlight the correct escape syntax, _(you could, if you wish change those)_.

Comment: Your syntax does not work at all. The %StringAfter must be %StringAfter% because of Batch. In a way it must be written like dynamic SQL with variables. Your syntax just appears to be extra steps. Why "NoProfile" before command?

Comment: `%StringAfter` is just a placeholder, not a variable, just change it to your string, or batch created variable as needed. The syntax is very simple, everything you are passing to `powershell` as `-Command` is enclosed in a single set of doublequotes, every doublequote inside those must be escaped with a backwards slash. That is the correct syntax, it has always worked for me on every system I've tried it on. If you want to know what `-NoProfile` does look it up, I'm not Alexa, Cortana, Google, or Siri

Comment: An example of what is inside `TEST.TXT` would also help us solve your issue. Please [edit] your question with that information.

Comment: Why make your life so hard with mixture of BAT and PS instead of using only PS?

Comment: I agree with  @Zett42, although a bit slower, Powershell is the way to go. Working with objects is a much richer way to script than just text using cmd, or bash, etc..

Comment: BAT is where I started the PS came in as an after fact because it was shorter code for the replace logic and I am a lazy typer. With my code almost done and just a few bugs I don't care about the most elegant solution. As all of this is a work around because our Teradata profiles are locked down and can not execute stored procedures. The test.txt file is BTEQ but essentially and example is that it contains the 3 variables ?YYYYMM $USER_ID and $USERPASSWORD

Comment: You think your Powershell code was shorter then doing it in pure batch? I bet I can do it in less characters in pure batch then your call to powershell.

Comment: I'm up for the challenge on that @squashman B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, using the syntax as suggested in my comments, but instead of multiple instances of PowerShell, a single one:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path \".\test.txt\") | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace(\"`$USER_ID\", \"%USER_ID%\").Replace(\"`$USERPASSWORD\", \"%USER_PASSWORD%\").Replace(\"?YYYYMM\", \"%SNAPSHOT%\") } | Set-Content -Path \".\test.txt\""
```

If you prefer to use single quotes in `PowerShell`, *(which in this case would be simpler to read and understand)*, then:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path '.\test.txt') | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('$USER_ID', '%USER_ID%').Replace('$USERPASSWORD', '%USER_PASSWORD%').Replace('?YYYYMM', '%SNAPSHOT%') } | Set-Content -Path '.\test.txt'"
```

These examples are based upon my interpretation of what your code is supposed to replace in `test.txt`, i.e. the literal strings, `$USER_ID`, `$USERPASSWORD` and `?YYYYMM`.

To return the string value of `%SNAPSHOT%` back to the literal string `?YYYYMM`, after having ran your `bteq` command, *(as you have in your code)*, then you could use either:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path \".\test.txt\") | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace(\"%SNAPSHOT%\", \"?YYYYMM\") } | Set-Content -Path \".\test.txt\""
```

Or

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path '.\test.txt') | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('%SNAPSHOT%', '?YYYYMM') } | Set-Content -Path '.\test.txt'"
```

If you are returning all three strings, not just one, then you could just use your chosen the first example, and switch the places of each string pair. However, for that, I seems simpler to me, to just `Set-Conent` to a new file, use that, then delete, than to keep modifying the same file.

Comment: I ran with this version of code ` POWERSHELL -Command "(Get-Content -Path '.\test.txt') | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('$USER_ID', '%USER_ID%').Replace('$USERPASSWORD', '%USER_PASSWORD%').Replace('?YYYYMM', '%SNAPSHOT%') } | Set-Content -Path '.\test.txt' ` thanks!

Comment: You obviously didn't bother trying to find out what `-NoProfile` does, then… BTW, a shortened version, using aliases and assuming locations and extensions are properly configured in the running system: `PowerShell -NoP "(GC 'test.txt')|%%{$_.Replace('$USER_ID','%USER_ID%').Replace('$USERPASSWORD','%USER_PASSWORD%').Replace('?YYYYMM','%SNAPSHOT%')}|SC 'test.txt'"`.